# Why are uninterned symbols used for package names and exports in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

In a [screen cast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1oMRw04W3E) ([archived blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110828050048/https://home.in.tum.de/%7Elehmanna/lisp-tutorial.html)) on Common List the author (Alexander Lehmann) uses uninterned symbols for package names and exports.

```
(defpackage #:foo
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:bar
           #:baz))

(in-package #:foo)
```

He also uses the sharp sign in front of anonymous functions.

```
(defun transposed (m)
  (make-instance 'matrix
                 :rows (matrix-cols m)
                 :cols (matrix-rows m)
                 :generator #'(lambda (i j) (matrix-at m j i))))
```

In the book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) the sharp sign isn't used for package names and exports as far as I have read.

What's the reason for using the uninterned symbols (the sharp sign) in these cases?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using an interned symbol pollutes the package you're currently in with symbols that are only used for their names anyway:

```
[1]> *package*
#<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>
[2]> (defpackage bar)
#<PACKAGE BAR>
[3]> (find-symbol "BAR")
BAR ;
:INTERNAL
```

Uninterned symbols don't do that:

```
;; Uninterned symbols don't cause symbol pollution:
[4]> (defpackage #:foo)
#<PACKAGE FOO>
[5]> (find-symbol "FOO")
NIL ;
NIL
```

You can also use strings directly, but since you're usually dealing with uppercase symbol names, they are less convenient to write:

```
[6]> (defpackage "BARFOO")
#<PACKAGE BARFOO>
[7]> (find-symbol "BARFOO")
NIL ;
NIL
```

### Example

To illustrate the problem, consider the following interaction:

```
[1]> (defpackage hello (:use cl) (:export hello))
#<PACKAGE HELLO>

;; Let's write some FOO stuff...
[2]> (defpackage foo (:use cl))
#<PACKAGE FOO>
[3]> (in-package foo)
#<PACKAGE FOO>

;; Oh, I forgot to import HELLO!
;; Let's fix that.
FOO[4]> (defpackage foo (:use cl hello))
*** - (COMMON-LISP:USE-PACKAGE (#<PACKAGE HELLO> #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP>)
      #<PACKAGE FOO>): 1 name conflicts remain
      Which symbol with name "HELLO" should be accessible in #<PACKAGE FOO>?

;; Oops.
```

Comment: So it's considered cleaner to write things like `(dotimes (#:i 10) (print "Woa"))` ?

Comment: @6502 That's an interesting case. :)  It is a bit different, since a `dotimes` form is usually located somewhere below an `in-package` form, so it will consistently be read in the specified package.  Polluting that isn't that bad—you do that all the time anyway.  `defpackage` and `in-package` are more troublesome in this regard because it's hard to predict what packages you're going to pollute when the respective form is read in; it may happen at any time, after all, and from more or less any place, especially when doing interactive development.

Comment: Yeah... after thinking a while I think your answer is correct. When a symbol is used **ONLY** for its name it's better to use an uninterned symbol. It also plays better with "modern mode" IIRC.

Comment: Did anyone address the OP's question abount `#'` in front of `lambda`s?  I don't know where I can use `#'(lambda (...) ...)` and not use `(lambda (...) ...)`.

Comment: Hang on... `(defpackage :foo)` *also* does not leave a symbol "FOO" in the current package. So you don't _need_ to use un-interned symbols for this issue, just avoid bare symbols.

Comment: @Dietrich But `(defpackage :foo)` does leave a symbol `FOO` in the `KEYWORD` package. After `(defpackage :foo)`, `(find-symbol "FOO" "KEYWORD")` returns `:FOO` and `:EXTERNAL`.

Answer (score 0):

`#'` is a shorthand for the `function` operator (this is used a few times in the Practical Common Lisp book).

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with conduits, and everything to do with using a symbol for its name and not its identity.

Comment: @jeha, your are right #' is used in Practical Common Lisp. I've fixed the question on that matter.