# Common Lisp package definition

Tags: package, common-lisp

In Common Lisp package definition, what is the difference between

```
(defpackage #:foo
    (:use :cl)
    (:export #:bar
        #:baz))

(in-package #:foo)
```

and

```
(defpackage :foo
    (:use :cl)
    (:export :bar
       :baz))

(in-package :foo)
```

I mean. When I have to use the "#" character? All these symbols are uninternerd, right?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894548/why-are-uninterned-symbols-used-for-package-names-and-exports-in-common-lisp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:foo` is the syntax for a keyword symbol, and `#:foo` is the syntax for an uninterned symbol. When a symbol is used primarily to get at the string that is its name (as in `defpackage` and `in-package`), I prefer to use uninterned symbols.

Here are the other options:

- use a keyword symbol; I don't like how this interns keyword symbols that show up in apropos and other places
- use a string; I don't like how this gratuitously breaks Allegro's "modern" mode
- use a plain symbol; I don't like how this both interns a symbol, and how it interns it in a potentially random package

Which style *you* or anyone else uses is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will adopt uninterned symbols to avoid some clashes in the namespace, as this link shows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894548/why-are-uninterned-symbols-used-for-package-names-and-exports-in-common-lisp . I think is the better approach.